# How to use MouseLeave to change cursor back after it leaves the canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to implement a crosshair cursor which will be activated through MouseEnter once the cursor enters the canvas. However, after the cursor has been changed to the crosshair, and even if it leaves the canvas, it still remains as the crosshair. I want the crosshair cursor to only be activated inside the canvas, and for the cursor to revert back to the default cursor once it leaves the canvas.

CSS:

```
#crosshair-h {
  width: 100%;
}

#crosshair-v {
  height: 100%;
}

.hair {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  background: transparent;
  border-top: 1px dotted #000;
  border-left: 1px dotted #000;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

#mousepos {
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  font: 14px arial;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Setup our variables
  var cH = $('#crosshair-h'),
      cV = $('#crosshair-v');

  $(this).on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - 1;
    var y = e.pageY - 1;
    cH.css('top', e.pageY);
    cV.css('left', e.pageX);

    $('#mousepos').css({
      top: e.pageY + 'px',
      left: e.pageX + 'px'
    }, 800);
    $('#mousepos').text( "X: " + x + "px, Y: " + y + "px");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Anchor Hover Effects
  $("a").hover(function() {
    $(".hair").stop().css({borderColor: "#fff"}, 800)},
     function() {
    $(".hair").stop().css({borderColor: "black"},800)
  });
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: can't you use [`cursor: crosshair;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) on your canvas css rules?

Comment: @jonatjano I'm using a custom crosshair as seen in this codepen: https://codepen.io/michaelsboost/pen/fnizu

Comment: _“I want the crosshair cursor to only be activated inside the canvas”_ - then bind the mousemove event to the canvas to begin with, not the whole document, and add a mouseout handler that hides the cursor element again …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the default crosshair cursor suffices, you can do this with a simple CSS hover rule:

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
canvas:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

If you really have need for the custom one, you can use a mouseleave or mouseout event on the canvas to remove the css class.